# Smart contract availability and diversity on Tezos

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, ligo, liquidity

I am researching about Tezos to what smart contract language there are available to use. When I look at the [TezosWiki](https://wiki.tezos.com/) and other sources I came up to with this list:

Tezos Smart Contract Languages:

- [Ligolang](https://ligolang.org/): Write SC in JS, Camel, Reason and Pascal.
- [Smartpy](https://smartpy.io/): SmartPy language is available through a Python library for building and analyzing Tezos smart contracts
- [Pymich](https://yourlabs.io/pyratzlabs/pymich): Write Pure Python and get Micheline Code with PyMich: Open Source Python to Tezos Micheline Smart Contract Source Code Transpiler
- [PyTezos](https://pytezos.org/): A Python library for interacting with Tezos blockchain,
  testing smart contracts, and writing Michelson scripts
- [Liquidity](https://liquidity-lang.org/): Liquidity is a high-level typed smart-contract language that compiles down to Michelson
- [Archetype](https://archetype-lang.org/): Archetype is a general purpose language to develop Smart Contracts on the Tezos blockchain, with exclusive features to ease development, tests and formal verification.
- [Morley](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/blob/master/code/morley/README.md): Morley is a Haskell-based framework for meta-programming Michelson smart contracts.

  - [Lorentz](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/blob/master/code/lorentz/README.md): Lorentz is a stack-based embedded Domain Specific Language (eDSL) in Haskell that compiles to Michelson.

    - [Indigo](https://wiki.tezos.com/build/smart-contracts/morley-framework/indigo): Indigo eDSL is a high-level language for developing Michelson contracts.

      - [Cleveland](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/tree/master/code/cleveland): Cleveland is a Haskell library for testing Michelson contracts.

I would say that Ligo and Smartpy are the most popular ones?

I assume PyTezos is not a real SC language?

Are people even using Liquidity or Archetype, Morley, Pymich..?

In the Tezos [Developer](https://tezos.com/developers/#discover) Portal only the three are mentioned: Smartpy, Ligo, Archetype.

But on [TezosWiki](https://wiki.tezos.com/build/smart-contracts/morley-framework/morley) I have Morley Framework listed too (Lorentz, Indigo, Cleveland).

What are developers actually using, and what do you do not recommend?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: For Pymich best to ask Bilal on Twitter, afaik he is behind it https://twitter.com/bilalelalamy/status/1402013376004476933

Answer (score 3):

We can confirm that LigoLANG is used by the following open-source projects:
[Quipuswap](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/quipuswap-core),
[Yupana](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/yupana-protocol-core),
[cTez](https://github.com/tezos-checker/ctez),
[Juster](https://github.com/juster-finance/juster-core/tree/master/contracts),
[Vortex DEX](https://github.com/Smartlinkhub/DEX),
[Flame DeFi](https://github.com/flamedefi/SpaceFarm/tree/main/contracts),
[Deku Sidechain](https://github.com/marigold-dev/deku/tree/main/src/tezos_interop),
[TzPortal Bridge](https://github.com/marigold-dev/tzportal/tree/main/contract).

Comment: Lot of learning content here : https://www.marigold.dev/learn

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that SmartPy is used by the following dApps (I restrict to the TOP 10 most used): [objkt.com](https://objkt.com/), [fx hash](https://www.fxhash.xyz/), Hic et Nunc ([repos](https://github.com/orgs/hicetnunc2000/repositories)), [Teia](https://teia.art/) ([contract](https://github.com/teia-community/teia-smart-contracts/tree/main/python)), [Versum](https://versum.xyz/), [Plenty](https://www.plentydefi.com/), [Kolibri](https://kolibri.finance/) (harbinger [contracts](https://github.com/tacoinfra/harbinger-contracts)), [Youves](https://youves.com/) ([contracts](https://github.com/youves-com/youves-smart-contract/tree/main/tracker)), [Tezotopia](https://tezotopia.com/home/), [LUGH](https://lugh.io/): EUR stable coin.

I don't know well the list for other languages but I will edit this message if people add more info in the answers.

Archetype is used by [Dogami](https://dogami.com/), [werenode](https://werenode.com/) and other projects.

Ligo is useb by
[baseDAO](https://github.com/tezos-commons/baseDAO),
[Quipuswap](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/quipuswap-core),
[Yupana](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/yupana-protocol-core),
[cTez](https://github.com/tezos-checker/ctez),
[Juster](https://github.com/juster-finance/juster-core/tree/master/contracts),
[Vortex DEX](https://github.com/Smartlinkhub/DEX),
[Flame DeFi](https://github.com/flamedefi/SpaceFarm/tree/main/contracts),
[Deku Sidechain](https://github.com/marigold-dev/deku/tree/main/src/tezos_interop),
[TzPortal Bridge](https://github.com/marigold-dev/tzportal/tree/main/contract).

Comment: Edited to add ligoLang projects.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume PyTezos is not a real SC language?

Indeed

> Are people even using Liquidity or Archetype, Morley, Pymich..?

Liquidity is not maintained anymore. Archetype and Morley are used. I don't know about Pymich.